# rgpd tarteaucitron js how define fallback methods for predefined servcies

Tags: javascript

Morning,
I want to use perdefined srvices (fb, recaptcha ...) of tarteaucitron rgpd script,
how can i define the fallback and js function like we do in custom services.
I followed insctructions in author website and all is ok,

```
    tarteaucitron.user.analyticsUa = 'UA-41016916-2';
    tarteaucitron.user.analyticsMore = function () { /* add here your optionnal ga.push() */ };
    (tarteaucitron.job = tarteaucitron.job || []).push('recaptcha');
    (tarteaucitron.job = tarteaucitron.job || []).push('youtubeapi');
    (tarteaucitron.job = tarteaucitron.job || []).push('facebook');
    (tarteaucitron.job = tarteaucitron.job || []).push('analytics');
```

The problem now is that i have to launch a jquery script to add listeners for captcha iframe, and since tarteaucitron works in async, DOM is not complete then and the correct way is to use like js section in custom service

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:
I took the script part dedicated for recaptcha field in (https://github.com/AmauriC/tarteaucitron.js/blob/master/tarteaucitron.services.js)
and i insert mycode where INSERT_YOUR_CODE is written

```
tarteaucitron.services.recaptcha = {
"key": "recaptcha",
"type": "api",
"name": "reCAPTCHA",
"uri": "https://policies.google.com/privacy",
"needConsent": true,
"cookies": ['nid'],
"js": function () {
    "use strict";
    window.tacRecaptchaOnLoad = tarteaucitron.user.recaptchaOnLoad || function() {};
    tarteaucitron.fallback(['g-recaptcha'], '');

    if (tarteaucitron.user.recaptchaapi === undefined) {
        tarteaucitron.addScript('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=tacRecaptchaOnLoad');
    } else {
        tarteaucitron.addScript('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=tacRecaptchaOnLoad&render=' + tarteaucitron.user.recaptchaapi);
    }
    INSERT_YOUR_CODE();
},
"fallback": function () {
    "use strict";
    var id = 'recaptcha';
    tarteaucitron.fallback(['g-recaptcha'], tarteaucitron.engage(id));
}
```

};